# What is the tree of life in Proverbs 11:30?

Tags: genesis, proverbs

While reading through Proverbs, I found a somewhat startling verse:

> [Proverbs 11:30 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs%2011:30&version=NIV)
>   The fruit of the righteous is a tree of life,
>     and the one who is wise saves lives.

My immediate thought was that this was a reference to eternal life, such as the tree of life in Genesis:

> [Genesis 3:22 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+3:22&version=NIV)
>   And the LORD God said, “The man has now become like one of us, knowing good and evil. He must not be allowed to reach out his hand and take also from the tree of life and eat, and live forever.”

However, I'm somewhat skeptical of my initial understanding of the passage.  I know Proverbs are supposed to be sayings that immediately make sense and are practical for every day usage.

So, is this "tree of life" found in Proverbs 11:30 the same as the one from Genesis 3?

Comment: See also, Proverbs 3:18, 13:12 and 15:4

Comment: cf. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/120820/170

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I doubt the difference is there in the original language, it seems to me the translators are correct to give the two references different articles - at least in the ESV, all the references in Genesis and Revelation are translated with the definite article, including the very first:

> <sup>9</sup>And out of the ground the LORD God made to spring up every tree that is pleasant to the sight and good for food. **The** tree of life was in the midst of the garden, and the tree of the knowledge of good and evil.   <sub>[Genesis 2:9 ESV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+2:9&version=ESV)</sub>

Just as there is a difference between "a god" and "The God", "The Tree of Life" is the ultimate form of "a tree of life" - so they are similar in nature and effect, but one is the ultimate expression and the other is a subordinate concept - the degree of subordination must be inferred from the context. In the case of Proverbs 11:30, the exegetical question is whether "the righteous/wise" save lives just in the literal sense, or whether the concept of 'eternal life' (which is a *quality* of life, not just a duration) is entangled and to what degree.

I would lean towards the literal sense because of the genre of Proverbs - that seems to be the sense in chapter 3 ('She' refers to 'wisdom' in the verse 18):

> <sup>18</sup>She is a tree of life to those who lay hold of her;
>      those who hold her fast are called blessed.   <sub>[ESV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs%203:18&version=ESV)</sub>

and:

> <sup>21</sup>My son, do not lose sight of these—
>      keep sound wisdom and discretion,
>    <sup>22</sup>and they will be **life** for your soul
>      and adornment for your neck.
>    <sup>23</sup> Then you will walk on your way securely,
>       and your foot will not stumble.
>    <sup>24</sup> If you lie down, you will not be afraid;
>      when you lie down, your sleep will be sweet.
>    <sup>25</sup> Do not be afraid of sudden terror
>      or of the ruin of the wicked, when it comes,
>    <sup>26</sup>for the LORD will be your confidence
>      and will keep your foot from being caught.  <sub>[ESV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs%203:21-26&version=ESV)</sub>

Comment: So, the fruit of righteousness is {a tree of life} meaning everlasting life?

Comment: I think you should connect "a tree of life" with "saves lives" in this proverb - often the two parts of a proverb say the same thing slightly differently, which is a Hebrew idiom.

Comment: `Although I doubt the difference is there in the original language ...` -- no need to start this off with an unnecessary qualification. :-) The Hebrew bears this out (Gen. *ʿēṣ haḥayyı̂m* = "*the* tree of [the] life"; Prov. *ʿēṣ ḥayyı̂m* = "*a* tree of life").

Answer (score 7):

[Malbim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malbim) ([ad loc.](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99_%D7%99%D7%90_%D7%9C)) explains that "tree of life" here means "source of eternal life of the soul", and interprets the verse as follows. (I'll boldface the parts that are translating the verse.) **The yield of a righteous person**, one who acts righteously, **is** that he's **a source of life** for those who follow his lead: their souls get eternal life<sup>[1]</sup> by their doing as he does. **And the wise man**, that is, someone who has acquired wisdom from his teachers and teaches, **draws** his students' **souls** along with him into wisdom.

So, no, this is not the same "tree of life" as in Genesis 3.

<sup>[1]</sup> Whatever that means.

Comment: All I know about Malbim is from Wikipedia, but it sounds like he wouldn't make this connection because of "his proven principle that there are no true synonyms in the Tanach."  ;-)  But in this case the connection certainly seems not to be there.  Would you say it's more similar to the tree analogy drawn in Psalm 1?

Comment: @JonEricson, the no-synonyms thing he's famous for refers to words, like כֶּבֶשׂ, _keves_, and כֶּשֶׂב, _kesev_, both of which mean "sheep", which he distinguishes between. I don't think it refers to different meanings (or referents) of the _same_ word, like _etz chayim_ ("tree of life") here.

Comment: Ah.  That does seem more likely (and manageable).  I am curious about your footnote, but comments aren't likely the best place to have that discussion.

Comment: But see העמ״ד ברא׳ ב׳ ט׳.

Answer (score 0):

Sensus Plenior (SP) is a modern term used to speak of the intended meaning of scripture which may have been hidden from the human author. As that intended meaning has been better understood, it has become a metaphor for the system of interpretation concerning the hidden meaning.  [What is sensus plenior?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/180/what-is-sensus-plenior-and-how-does-it-impact-the-field-of-hermeneutics)

In SP all trees are the same tree. All donkeys are one donkey, all men are one man. Each 'story' is a story of Christ and is part of the mystery which has been hidden from the beginning. 1 Co 2:7

They all lay atop of each other like transparencies, with details of each adding to the singular picture of Christ.

The tree of life is also the tree of death (knowledge of good and evil which caused death). In the garden scene they are described as two trees, but in Revelation they have grown together over the stream. It is a picture of the cross, which through the death of Christ gives life.

In Pr 11:30 The righteous one is Christ. HIS fruit is the life given through the cross. This is the layer which speaks of Christ.

The application layer derives from the idea that we are made to be 'like' Christ as his bride.

Then the righteous one is the bride of Christ, who is fruitful and multiplying; fruitful by the fruit of the Spirit, and multiplying by teaching and preaching the cross. This fruitfulness produces life as others come to Christ.

Some have suggested that the idea that the New Testament is based on the Old Testament is offensive on its face. But the claim that Christ fulfilled the prophecies of the Old Testament has been the claim of the church since the days of the Bereans when they examined Paul's teaching in the context of the Old Testament. Acts 17:11.

Note: The idea of the 'transparency' mentioned above, is a summary or simplification of some of the 32 rules of Rabbi Eliezer, which are demonstrably used by NT authors.

E8. Binyan ab mi-katub ehad: Application of a provision found in one passage only to passages which are related to the first in content but do not contain the provision in question.

E10. Dabar shehu shanuy (repeated expression): Repetition implies a special meaning.

E17. A point which is not clearly explained in the main passage may be better elucidated in another passage.

E21. If one object is compared to two other objects the best part of both the latter forms the tertium quid of comparison.

E22. A passage may be supplemented and explained by a parallel passage.

E23. A passage serves to elucidate and supplement its parallel passage.

E27. Mi-ma’al: Interpretation through the preceding.

E31. Postposition of the precedent. Many phrases which follow must be regarded as properly preceding, and must be interpreted accordingly in exegesis.

E32. Many portions of the Bible refer to an earlier period than to the sections which precede them, and vice versa.

Comment: I don't recognize *sensus plenior* in your brief descriptive account in your first sentence. It seem idiosyncratic to me. Can you point me to others who share that definition?

Comment: The usage is specific to a bulk of conversations here concerning the hermeneutic which elicits an exegesis in an attempt to reproduce the exegesis of NT authors. You are probably more familiar with the discussions concerning SP as a theory.  http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/2060/what-are-the-strict-set-of-rules-followed-by-sensus-plenior

Comment: 'Sensus Plenior', is used to give a context for the answer given so that it is clearly seen to be different from what most readers will be familiar with.

Comment: @David... I added better explanation of sensus plenior and a better answer to the OP.  I must have been sleeping when I originally posted it.

Comment: Blind down voting again?  Please add comments to help improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Genesis 3:22 And the LORD God said, "The man has now become like one of us, knowing good and evil. He must not be allowed to reach out his hand and take also from the tree of life and eat, and live forever."

from **the** tree
מֵעֵ֣ץ (mê·‘êṣ)
Preposition-m | Noun - masculine singular construct
Strong's Hebrew 6086: Tree, trees, wood

of **the** life,
הַֽחַיִּ֔ים (ha·ḥay·yîm)
Article | Noun - masculine plural
Strong's Hebrew 2416: Alive, raw, fresh, strong, life

> Proverbs 11:30 The fruit of the righteous is a tree of life, and he that wins souls is wise.

is **a** tree
עֵ֣ץ (‘êṣ)
Noun - masculine singular construct
Strong's Hebrew 6086: Tree, trees, wood

of life,
חַיִּ֑ים (ḥay·yîm)
Noun - masculine plural
Strong's Hebrew 2416: Alive, raw, fresh, strong, life

1. It is clear from the Hebrew that the definite article applies only to the Genesis tree and not to the Proverb tree.
2. "live forever" appears only to the Genesis tree.
3. The Proverb tree is associated with winning souls.

In conclusion, the tree of life in Proverb is a symbol/shadow of the true tree of eternal life in Genesis.

Good question.

Answer (score 0):

**What is the tree of life in Proverbs 11:30?**

Proverbs 11:30 (NIV)

> The fruit of the righteous is a tree of life, and the one who is wise
> saves lives.

The fruit of the righteous **(Man)**, by means of his conduct, speech, and spiritual nourishment of a righteous man can help others to develop godly qualities, are led to serve God thus helping them to eventually receive the life that God promises.

John 5:28-29  (NASB)

> 28 "Do not marvel at this; for an hour is coming, in which all who are
> in the tombs will hear His voice, 29 and will come forth; those who
> did the good deeds to a **resurrection of life,** those who committed the
> evil deeds to a resurrection of judgment.

The expression "tree of life" also is to be found at Proverbs 15:4 and 13:12 and is used in a symbolic form. The "tree of life" in Genesis was an actual tree that God would have permitted  Adam to eat of it,  provided he proved himself worthy according to God's requirements.

Genesis 3:22-23  (NASB)

> 22 "Then the Lord God said, “Behold, the man has become like one of
> Us, knowing good and evil; and now, **he might stretch out his hand, and
> take also from the tree of life, and eat, and live forever”**— 23,
> therefore, the Lord God sent him out from the garden of Eden, to
> cultivate the ground from which he was taken."