Do the Jews recognize Abraham to David as 14 generations? I know Matthew's gospel makes the point, but did Jews (before Matt) make mention of 14 gen?
Matthews gospels makes a significant point of there being 14 generations between Abram and David.  Did Jews do the same before Matthew wrote?  Second temple period?

This question would better asked on the Jewish Stack Exchange.

Question has been addressed before this - https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/927/what-is-the-significance-of-14-generations-in-matthew-s-account-of-jesuss-gen

This question belongs on Judaism SE. It's a good question

Welcome to the group DrJJ007. I think this is a different question than the one mentioned by @RobCallicotte because yours asks about the culture at the time of Matthew, not the meaning of the text. I also have to disagree with Avi about JudaismSE. That site is not interested in Christian texts but I was able to find a bit of relevant info there, which I included in my answer below. Also please be informed that the moderators sometimes close questions if they do not address a specific chapter and verse, so please edit your q. to include this.

I won't answer for "the Jews" generally, but there is indeed an classical Jewish writing from the 12th century c.e. that understands the generations this way. It speaks of 15 generations from Abraham to Solomon:
Midrash Shemot Rabbah 15

On the first of Nisan, the moon begins to shine, and it gradually
increases its light until the fifteenth day, and its orb becomes full.
From fifteen until thirty days, its light wanes, and on the thirtieth
it is not seen. So Israel, for fifteen generations from Abraham until
Solomon. Abraham began to give light, as it is stated: “Who has risen
from the east, righteousness attends his footsteps” (Isaiah 41:2).
Isaac came, and he also gave light, as it is stated: “Light is sown
for the righteous” (Psalms 97:11). Jacob came and added light, as it
is stated: “The light of Israel shall be fire” (Isaiah 10:17). And
then Judah, Peretz, Ḥetzron, Ram, Aminadav, Naḥshon, Salmon, Boaz.
Oved, Yishai, David.  When Solomon came, the orb of the moon became
full, as it is stated: “Solomon sat on the throne of the Lord as king”
(I Chronicles 29:23)

Since Solomon came one generation after David, this text clearly sees 14 generations between David and Abraham. I am not aware any texts that would tell us how Jews thought about this question at the time that Matthew was written.

With the traditional understanding of a generation as around 20 years, that would be under 300 years, which seems remarkably short even bearing in mind the culture that developed these narratives. You would have to squeeze in the whole exile in Egypt, the wandering in the wilderness, the entirety of the period of the judges, and a few other kings, among other things.
